# Having issues in xcode 6.1 throws exception error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am completely new here! Learning by the seat of my pants.  Trying to create a login and Password screen with a label. I  have a textfield for User Name, one for Password, a label that says "Please Login" and a button to push.  Everything is fine until I get to the button.  I drag the button to the screen and set it up how I want, but when I try to command left click drag the button to the code, I get no options to make it an action.

So it comes in as @IBOutlet var theButton: UIView! which is wrong.  The only options I get is Outlet and Outlet Collections, I can type over UIView and make it UIButton.

So I manually type in :

```
@IBAction func theButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var usr = "debf"
    var pw = "cando"

    if theTextfieldUsername.text == usr && theTextfieldPassword.text == pw {
        println("Login Sucessful")
        theTextfieldUsername.resignFirstResponder()
        theTextfieldPassword.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else {
        println("Login Not Sucessful. Please Signup")
        theTextfieldUsername.resignFirstResponder()
        theTextfieldPassword.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

And  when I run it, it throws and exception and I can not figure out what the problem is! I get:

```
2014-10-24 17:45:23.096 UFMTest[4146:1713077] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UFMTest.ViewController 0x79c70990> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key theSubmitButt.'
```

`theSubmitButt` was the name of the button the first time I made it, I've deleted it and redone it several times but I still get this.

Any suggestions?

Here is the entire code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  UFMTest
//
//  Created by Deborah Flack on 10/24/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Armidido Inc. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var theTextfieldUsername: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var theTextfieldPassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var theLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func theButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        var usr = "debf"
        var pw = "cando"

        if theTextfieldUsername.text == usr && theTextfieldPassword.text == pw {
            println("Login Sucessful")
            theTextfieldUsername.resignFirstResponder()
            theTextfieldPassword.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        else {
            println("Login Not Sucessful. Please Signup")
            theTextfieldUsername.resignFirstResponder()
            theTextfieldPassword.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Comment: After manually typing in the IBAction, then connect your button by control dragging.

Comment: I tried that, and I get still get the exception error. I've deleted the button, and the code for the button, and recreated it, re did all the code, and the exception still throws but refers to the previous named button

Comment: if you post to github, someone can debug it quickly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, even after you deleted `theSubmitButt` code from from `ViewController`, Storyboard is still trying to connect the button to `theSubmitButt`.

To resolve that, check "Connection Inspector" out in Interface Builder, and disconnect it from `theSubmitButt` by clicking `x` button.

[image: screenshot]